# Problem with determining the circles inscribed into polygons

Tags: r

I have a problem with determining the circles inscribed in polygons. In any case, regardless of the specified tolerance, I get an error. I'd like to get an effect like this post: https://twitter.com/edzerpebesma/status/1357372616126959621 I have several hundred polygons, but the problem also occurs with a single feature.

Reprex below :

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.1, GDAL 3.4.3, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)
  
obszar1_txt <-  "POLYGON ((647269.1 480765.2, 647127 481173, 646945.4 481420.8, 646515.9 482121.1,
646467.8 482189.5, 645865.4 483485.4, 645808.4 483985.8, 645671.2 485244.5, 645702.2 485276.6,
647363.2 485293.2, 647468.9 485233.9, 648042.8 484365.1, 648236.3 484041.8, 649024.2 482839,
649261.2 482496.4, 650059.6 481267.4, 650594.1 480460.5, 650316.4 480264.6, 649822.6 480126.8,
648489.5 479803.7, 647907.1 479774.8, 647540 480119.8, 647269.1 480765.2))"

obszar1_txt <- tibble(ID = 1, geometry = obszar1_txt)

obszar1 <- st_as_sf(obszar1_txt, wkt = "geometry")

st_inscribed_circle(obszar1, dTolerance = 1)
#> Error in `st_geometry<-.sf`(`*tmp*`, value = value): zmienna nrow(x) == length(value) nie ma wartości TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the example in `?st_inscribed_circle`, `x` has to be of type geometry set and not simple feature collection. Is this what you're looking for?

```r
obszar1 <- st_as_sf(obszar1_txt, wkt = "geometry")

c <- st_inscribed_circle(obszar1 |> st_geometry(), dTolerance = 1)

c
#> Geometry set for 2 features  (with 1 geometry empty)
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 647206.2 ymin: 479855.5 xmax: 649859.6 ymax: 482508.9
#> CRS:           NA
#> POLYGON ((649859.6 481182.2, 649857.7 481112.8,...
#> POLYGON EMPTY

plot(obszar1 |> st_geometry(), reset = FALSE)
plot(c, border = "red", add = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

By the way, better don't forget to specify the `crs` argument when calling `st_as_sf()`.

Comment: Thank you. The description of the "geos_unary" functions says "x - object of class sfg, sfc or sf", I didn't look at the example. Do you know why the function `st_inscribed_circle` returns 2 geometries, including one empty?

Comment: I was wondering too - no idea, unfortunately. However, this also applies to the official example `nc_t <- st_transform(nc, "EPSG:2264"); st_inscribed_circle(st_geometry(nc_t))` returning "geometry set for 200 features (with 100 geometries empty)".

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and answer. Fortunately, when the empty geometries are filtered out, the circles are in the same order as the polygons, so you can do `dplyr::bind_cols` for further analysis (e.g. area comparision). I remember setting CRS on `st_as_sf`. In the example, I didn't make it as simple as possible.